# Checkbox unchecked button is disabled

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-directive

Here in my stackblitz , Once I clicked the checkbox it will disable the other buttons. So I want to happen here is:

if I clicked Checkbox(Sample1) button1 will be enabled. if unchecked button1 is disabled

hoping someone can help me thank you so much in advance!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-disable-button-il3rqn?file=src/app/services/button-disable.service.ts

Comment: Please post the (relevant) code, otherwise it's impossible to know what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Always we want to control two or more elements "not relationated" we need two or more variables (or an Array)

So, the fisrt is that our service dispatch an array of booleans

```
export class ButtonDisableService {

  private _disableButton: BehaviorSubject<boolean[]> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean[]>([]);

  get disableButton(): Observable<boolean[]> {
    return this._disableButton.asObservable();
  }

  //see that we need in toogle indicate the "index"
  toogleDisable(index:number){
    this._disableButton.value[index]=!this._disableButton.value[index]
    this._disableButton.next(this._disableButton.value);
  }
}
```

Then in button, we use "map" rxjs operator to get only one element of the array

button 1

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.disablee = this.buttonDisable.disableButton.pipe(
           map((x:boolean[])=>x[0]));
  }
```

and button 2 (we check if x.length>0)

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.disablee = this.buttonDisable.disableButton.pipe(
           map((x:boolean[])=>x.length>0?x[1]:null));
  }
```

Finally in master.html

```
<input type="checkbox" (click)="toogleButtonStatee(0)">sample1
<input type="checkbox" (click)="toogleButtonStatee(1)">sample2 <br><br>

toogleButtonStatee(index:number){
    this.buttonDisable.toogleDisable(index);
}
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-disable-button-r7bydw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fbutton-disable.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fbutton1%2Fbutton1.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fmaster-button%2Fmaster-button.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fbutton2%2Fbutton2.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fbutton1%2Fbutton1.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fbutton2%2Fbutton2.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fmaster-button%2Fmaster-button.component.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Eliseo, You're really a great help!   [disabled]="!(disablee|async)" so i need to this to disable first the button then when I clicked the checkbox it will enable.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. If you want your buttons to be initially `disabled`, use a different initial value for your `BehaviorSubject`.

And if you only want one button to be affected, then use a different condition for your second button (you might want to rephrase that part of your question; it's not 100% clear what you're trying to achieve).